# jQuery Selector Not Functioning as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I am running into an issue with some jQuery code. I cannot get the selector to function properly. The selector is suppose to wrap all `input`s on my page with a `div` **except** for `checkboxes` and `radios`. Here is the jQuery selector I am using to try and accomplish this:

```
//Wrap input tags in col-sm-9
$("#custom-form-builder input[type!=radio], input[type!=checkbox]").not('#custom-form-builder .datepickercontroller').wrap('<div class="col-sm-9">');
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group required checkboxerrr">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Multiselect</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 control-class">
        <div class="checkbox check-info">
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" id="checkbox5">
          <label for="checkbox5" class="no-asterisk">Action</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox check-info">
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" id="checkbox6">
          <label for="checkbox6" class="no-asterisk">Mark as read</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After this jQuery selector is executed, the `radios` are not wrapped in this: `<div class="col-sm-9">`. However, my `checkboxes` are. Here is the final HTML after the jQuery selector is executed:

```
<div class="form-group required checkboxerrr">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Multiselect</label>
<div class="control-class col-sm-9">
    <div class="checkbox check-info">
      <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" id="checkbox5"></div>
      <label for="checkbox5" class="no-asterisk col-sm-3 control-label">Action</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox check-info">
      <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" id="checkbox6"></div>
      <label for="checkbox6" class="no-asterisk col-sm-3 control-label">Mark as read</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A `!=` attribute selector doesn’t exist. Try this: `#custom-form-builder input:not([type=radio]):not([type=checkbox])`

Comment: @CBroe actually it does, had to look it up myself http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

Comment: @charlietfl: Ah, thanks, I wasn’t aware that jQuery had that as an extension to native CSS selectors.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/0n7ndo6k/ your html has no `id=custom-form-builder` though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your original code I guess you want the input elements to satisfy the following conditions:

- A descendant of `#custom-form-builder`
- Neither a checkbox or a radio element
- Does not have the class `datepickercontrol`

However, your selector, `"#custom-form-builder input[type!=radio], input[type!=checkbox]"`, is a little problematic (in terms of logic), as it:

1. Ignores non-radio inputs in `#custom-form-builder`, but
2. Ignores non-checkbox input *in the entire HTML document*

---

There are several ways that you can do this.

**Use `.not()`, a jQuery method**

The advantage of using `.not()` is that you can always access the parent element and/or perform DOM traversal of the cached elements within jQuery by chaining additional methods.

```
$("#custom-form-builder :input")
.not('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="text"], .datepickercontrol')
.wrap('<div class="col-sm-9" />');
```

**Bonus: Use `.filter()`, a jQuery method**

The `.filter()` function allows you to conditionally remove items that are initially fetched by your selector. You can then apply chained methods after this function onto a subset of elements after filtering. This approach may sound long-winded for a simple application, but is very useful for complicated conditional filtering.

```
$("#custom-form-builder :input")
.filter(function() {
    return ($(this).attr('type') != 'checkbox' && $(this).attr('type') != 'radio' && !$(this).hasClass('.datepickercontrol'));
})
.wrap('<div class="col-sm-9" />');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is invalid for input type. You have to use [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.

```
$("#custom-form-builder input:not[type=radio], input:not[type=checkbox]").not('#custom-form-builder .datepickercontroller').wrap('<div class="col-sm-9">');
```

Comment: Good to note that at times using `.not()` might be more desirable, especially when traversing DOM is needed ;) but this is a very elegant solution, too!

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, this works somewhat, but I am getting the following error in the console which is causing the page to stop working completely. Here is the error: `[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.replace')
 (anonymous function) (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 PSEUDO (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 ht (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 compile (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 vt (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 vt (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)
 nt (jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2)`

Answer (score 0):

wrong syntax in your code try this:

```
$("#custom-form-builder").not('input[type=radio]').not('input[type=checkbox]')not('#custom-form-builder .datepickercontroller').wrap('<div class="col-sm-9">');
```